# How can we read GPS in Silverlight 4 application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, gps

I need to read the GPS receiver attached to a COM port.

How can we read GPS in a Silverlight 4 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of option I can think of.

- In OOB (out of browser) mode you can
  access COM components to do pretty
  much anything. That does mean you
  will need a COM component to access
  your GPS.
- You can create javascript apps that can send information to the
  Silverlight component within the
  browser. I have seen this used to
  pass on card scanner information to a
  Silverlight app.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is the catch-all of creating a web service to pass along the data.

Comment: Hi HiTech I have created app that read the COM port in the silverlight with the port.REadString() but this things give me encrypted string like this - "?\0x??x?x?x" - Can you suggest why get this type of string ?

Comment: @Tushar Maru:@ This is where my knowledge runs out. If you are going to program for GPS devices, I assume you would already be an expert in that area. Tiem for a different question under GPS methinks :)

Comment: @grimus: You want to create a webservice to provide GPS hardware info??? Great if you want to know where your service is hosted I guess :)